# Can not convert output to string

Tags: string, powershell

I cannot format this command to string. The code below returns `$r` as an empty string. Why?

```
$f = gwmi -ComputerName PCname -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name='process.exe'"|
  select {$_.WorkingSetSize/1MB}|fl
$r = $f.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the object type returned by Format-List you will see that it is an array of System.Object.

```
$f = gwmi -ComputerName PCname -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name='process.exe'"| `
select {$_.WorkingSetSize/1MB}|fl 
$r | get-member
```

If you just need the values of working set, try this:

```
gwmi -ComputerName PCname -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name='process.exe'" | `
select @{label='WorkingSetSize';expression={$_.WorkingSetSize/1MB}}| `
select -expandproperty WorkingSetSize
```

Answer (score 0):

`Format-List` produces an array of strings, not a single string, so `$f.ToString()` should give you `System.Object[]`. To convert an array to a single string you can pipe it into the `Out-String` cmdlet:

```
$f = gwmi -ComputerName PCname -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name='process.exe'" |
     select {$_.WorkingSetSize/1MB} | fl
$g = $f | Out-String
```

However, as mentioned above, you should at least get `System.Object[]`, not an empty string, so double-check the value of `$f`.

Answer (score 0):

What I find is that -Filter "name='process.exe'" does not work for me.  So I substituted

```
| where {$_.name -match "Process"}
```

This is my result, I also substituted LocalHost for PCname and removed |fl

```
$r = gwmi -ComputerName localhost -Class Win32_Process | where {$_.name -match "Process"} |
select @{label='WorkingSetSize';expression={$_.WorkingSetSize/1MB}} | 
select -expandproperty WorkingSetSize 
$r.ToString()
```